# RegEx: How to capture multi-line text BETWEEN '({' and '})' …

Tags: javascript, regex

### I need to capture the **first** occurrence of a **multi-line** block of text **AFTER** a specified word.

Essentially, given the name/label of a JavaScript object, I need to capture the object contents.

### Example:  Given the following text…

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store';

import type { NewFile, EditorCacheType, EditorObj, State } from '../types';

const DirectoryData: Writable<State> = writable<State>({
  mainDir: '',
  fileTree: [],
  openFilePath: '',
  fileRead: false,
  stateObj: {},
  activeFile: '',
  rename: false,
  deleteFile: false,
  activeDir: '',
  createFile: false,
  createFolder: false,
  createMainFile: false,
  createMainFolder: false,
  reload: false,
  activeFolder: '',
});

const openTabs: Writable<NewFile[]> = writable<NewFile[]>([]);

const currentTabFilePath: Writable<string> = writable<string>('');
```

### I want FIND `const DirectoryData` THEN capture the following

```
                                                      ({
  mainDir: '',
  fileTree: [],
  openFilePath: '',
  fileRead: false,
  stateObj: {},
  activeFile: '',
  rename: false,
  deleteFile: false,
  activeDir: '',
  createFile: false,
  createFolder: false,
  createMainFile: false,
  createMainFolder: false,
  reload: false,
  activeFolder: '',
});
```

### I have tried many combinations around…

`const regex = /DirectoryData((.*|\n|\r|\n\r|\0)*)/gmi;`

### But it either capture til the end of the file/string or nothing‼️

Comment: You can try: `/(?<=DirectoryData.*)\(\{[\s\S]+\}\)/`.

Comment: Have you tried using the TypeScript compiler API?

Comment: You can use a capture group `\bconst\s+DirectoryData:.*\({([^]+?)}\)` https://regex101.com/r/lMJwz5/1